# How to set the background color of system navigation bar to the one of the new Bottom Navigation bar in Material 3? (Android)

Tags: java, android, colors, material-design, themes

I tried using this:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorSurface</item>
```

but it isn't giving me the desired result.. like the one shown in the docs:
[image]
[image]

I recently switched to Material 3.

If you want full code of the app: https://github.com/Sujal1245/WALLisWALL-Wallpaper-App

Comment: If any more precise information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new class in Material Components library in version 1.5.0 (specifically 1.5.0-alpha03) and up that solves this very problem, the [SurfaceColors](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/elevation/SurfaceColors.java) class.

To use it, call the `getColor` method on one of the constant values in the `SurfaceColors` enum for the desired color. Here is an example:

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(this));
```

`SURFACE_2` is what is used (or its equivalent) by `BottomNavigationView`. It works with and without Dynamic Coloring (including night mode). I have also observed this solution being used in the Files by Google app.

[Here is a screenshot on Android 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f2sJ.png)

[And here is a screenshot on Android 12.1 with Dynamic Coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIqtu.png)

If you're also curious about the exact shadow used by Google for the `BottomNavigationView`, it is a 5dp tall gradient drawable from #00000000 to #33333333.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will give it a try.

Comment: Just tried. It's working as expected :)

Comment: If I want to set a background color to the system navigation bar just like the screen color? then how to do it

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Android 14, it gives me different colors.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71178852/10276438). If you are using Dynamic Coloring. Call this method after setting Dynamic Coloring. Otherwise, you will always get the same color without dynamic effects.

Code in Kotlin

```
DynamicColors.applyIfAvailable(this) // After this
window.navigationBarColor = SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(this)
```

Thanks.